# How to store user credentials in portable apps?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, xamarin, portable-class-library, passwordvault

Windows Runtime (WinRT/8) has a PasswordVault service which implements storage for user passwords and etc. But what about Xamarin's Android, iOS and WinPhone SDKs?

Application that use encryption, if i will implement it natively in code, get covered by restrictions, if am correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Akavache package to save login credentials. See the exstensive documentation on the GitHub: https://github.com/akavache/Akavache/#extension-method-documentation

An example would be:

```
BlobCache.Secure.SaveLogin(Username, Password);
```